# Acumatica oAuth API GET request requiring login

Tags: oauth, acumatica

I am sending an OAuth request to an Acumatica endpoint, and it is responding with "You are not logged in.". I was under the impression that retrieving an access token, then sending it to an OAuth request would not require an actual login previous.  If this is correct, then any idea why I'm getting this message?

I first POST to the .../identityconnect/token URL with client_secret, client_id, username, password, etc. to retrieve an access token.  Then I use the access token on an OAuth GET request, and receive the login error (401).

Comment: What grant_type and scope are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a 3rd party license manager customization package that was published and was throwing an error and preventing a successful OAuth submittal.  This was discovered by reviewing the Request Profiler.

Comment: Wow, Tony - that is quite the detective job you did there!